# Error compiling thread program in codeblocks 12.11

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

my thread program is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

void t()
{
cout<<"from thread\n";
}

 int main()
 {
 thread i(&t);
 cout <<"from main\n";
 i.join();
  }
```

but it shows following error in codeblocks:

```
  1)'thread ' was not declared in this scope 

  2)expected ';' before 'i'

  3)'i' was not declared in this scope
```

How can I solve it?I am using windows and codeblocks 12.11

Comment: Which compiler are you using under the hood?

Comment: sorry could not under stand you

Comment: CodeBlocks is an IDE, which uses a compiler. I understand it supports different compilers, so I wanted to know which one you are using.

Comment: oh got it I am using mingw gcc  4.7  compiler

Comment: When I compile the above code on Linux, I get your errors if I forget to add the -std=c++0x file to my g++ compiler. BUT if I add the file, it will compile flawlessly. Note that I also get another message in front of your errors, that does explain what to do:     from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Unfortunately the version of GCC Code::Blocks uses does not support the features of C++11 that you want. Turning on the option `-std=c++0x` will only ugrade the compiler to  a less recent version of the new Standard. That means you will only enable basic support of C+11.

Comment: @mubir You should upgrade to a newer compiler. Try [Visual C++2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads). I believe they have a more recent compiler.